# Alarm sound at certain time of a day

Tags: php, html, audio, alarm

The idea is to play an alarm from html/php web-page via a TV hanging near the school canteen reminding students to wash their hands. The TV is used as a tabloid screen for school events and news.
The piece of code I'm using on this page is as follows:

```
<?php 
$hour = date('G');
$day  = date('1..5'); // 1..7 for Monday to Friday

if (($hour >= 11.05  && $hour <= 11.35)  // 5am - 7am
||  ($hour >= 12.15 && $hour <= 12.30) // 10am - 12 noon
||  ($hour >= 21.10 && $hour <= 21.30) // 10am - 12 noon
||  ($day == 1-5)                  // Monday - Friday
) { ?>
  <audio src="Audio/sirena.mp3" autoplay="true" loop="loop">
<?php } ?>
```

This only plays it once the page is uploaded onto the server, and if it falls within the times above. Otherwise, it stays silent. And, strangely it plays only on my home PC on Chrome/IE/Mozilla and it doesn't play completely on school PCs.
Bear in mind the page auto refreshes itself every 5 min.

Would appreciate if someone gave a hint on event listeners or anything else.

Comment: It looks like the last par of that OR condition with the day would make it ignore all the times, and the `$hour` numbers don't look like they're in the right format to compare to the output of `date('G')`.

Comment: On a not really programming related sidenote, it seems like people would become desensitized pretty quickly to an alarm sound if they heard it that frequently.

Comment: Regarding the date(G) - 24-hour format of an hour (0 to 23).

If I write -  ||  ($day == 1-5)  with dots ||  ($day == 1..5)  I get Error 500 Internal server error.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your code.

In `$day  = date('1..5');`, `'1..5'` isn't a valid format for `date()`. That will just return the string `1..5`. You want `date('w')`.

`date('G')` returns the hour in 24-hour format, so `$date` will be a string representation of an integer. In your `if` condition you are comparing it to floats. Since all of the different time conditions are various decimals above the same integers, `$date` will never match any of them. For example, if the time is 11:30 AM, `$date` will be `'11'`, which is not between `11.05` and `11.35`. (Obviously, neither is `'10'` or `'12'`.)

In the last part of the `if` condition, you have `|| ($day == 1-5)`. There are two problems with that. First, `1-5` does not mean *"between one and five"*; it means *"one minus five"*. And second, the fact that this is an additional non-nested `or` condition means that it negates all of the various time comparisons, because whenever *any part* of an `or` condition is true, the *entire condition* evaluates to true. If it was `|| ($day >= 1 && $day <= 5)`, then the `if` would be true all day every Monday through Friday. As it is, it's true all day only on Thursday.

I added an updated version that *I think* will do what you want it to (based on the comments in your code). I used some kind of strange indentation in the `if` condition to hopefully show the grouping a little better. Basically it needs to check the day *and* check a group of time conditions. Note the different format for time (`'Gi'`), which gets the hour and minute in a format that can be compared to integer values in the `if` condition.

```
$day  = date('w');
$time = date('Gi');

if ( ($day > 0 && $day < 6)                 // Monday - Friday
      && (                                  // AND
          ($time >= 1105  && $time < 1135)  //   time range 1
          ||                                //   OR
          ($time >= 1215 && $time < 1230)   //   time range 2
          ||                                //   OR
          ($time >= 2110 && $time < 2130)   //   time range 3
         )
   )
echo '<audio src="Audio/sirena.mp3" autoplay="true" loop="loop">';
```

Comment: Thanks. It is very crucial to get it to work down to minutes, like 11:05 till 11:35, since anything outside of these times are lessons. Which requires the TV to be quiet.

I've tried replacing $hour = date('G'); with $hour = time(); and $hour = date('HH:MM'), but it didn't do the trick.

Is there a way ot get it down to minute?

Comment: Oh, yeah, that's possible. So, the comments in your code that say `5am - 7am`, etc. don't mean anything?

Comment: Can you expand on it? 

Plus, it now works in Mozilla/IE/Chrome, but it doesn't in Chromium on Linux... Any ideas on that? We set it to EU times, so it is 24 hour format too.

Comment: Update. It does play on Chromium. The times were pass the actual clock time. 

Problem is, when 11.05, instead of exact 11is written, the sound refuses to play. I removed $day now.

Comment: @user72160 I updated the answer to handle minutes instead of just hours.

Comment: Thanks for accommodating the code. I will pair it with the following script to refresh the page in advance at a given time (lower). In my case at 11.05. Otherwise, there is no event listener to play the audio once the actual time reaches the stated time range.

Comment: <script>
function refreshAt(hours, minutes, seconds) {
    var now = new Date();
    var then = new Date();

    if(now.getHours() > hours ||
       (now.getHours() == hours && now.getMinutes() > minutes) ||
        now.getHours() == hours && now.getMinutes() == minutes && now.getSeconds() >= seconds) {
        then.setDate(now.getDate() + 1);
    }
    then.setHours(hours);
    then.setMinutes(minutes);
    then.setSeconds(seconds);

    var timeout = (then.getTime() - now.getTime());
    setTimeout(function() { window.location.reload(true); }, timeout);
}
</script>

Comment: <script>
refreshAt(21,25,0); //Will refresh the page at 3:35pm
</script>